# Writing a pipelineplugin in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a Jenkinsplugin. I have set up a pipeline script, when I execute the script its calling some shell scripts and setting up a pipeline. Thats working fine.

Example of my code:

```
node('master') {
        try {            
            def appWorkspace = './app/'
            def testWorkspace = './tests/'

            stage('Clean up') { 
            //    cleanWs()

            }

            stage('Build') {
                parallel (
                    app: {
                        dir(appWorkspace) {
                            git changelog: false, credentialsId: 'jenkins.git', poll: false, url: 'https://src.url/to/our/repo'

                            dir('./App') {
                                sh "#!/bin/bash -lx \n ./gradlew assembleRelease"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tests: {
                        dir(testWorkspace) {
                            git changelog: false, credentialsId: 'jenkins.git', poll: false, url: 'https://src.url/to/our/repo'

                            sh "#!/bin/bash -lx \n nuget restore ./Tests/MyProject/MyProject.sln"
                            sh "#!/bin/bash -lx \n msbuild ./Tests/MyProject/MyProject.Core/ /p:Configuration=Debug"
                        }
                    }
                )
            }

            stage('Prepare') {
                parallel (
                    'install-apk': { 
                        sh '''#!/bin/bash -lx
                        result="$(adbExtendedVersion shell pm list packages packagename.app)"

                        if [ ! -z "$result" ]
                        then
                            adbExtendedVersion uninstall packagename.app
                        fi

                        adbExtendedVersion install ''' + appWorkspace + '''/path/to/app-release.apk'''
                    },
                    'start-appium': { 
                        sh "#!/bin/bash -lx \n GetAllAttachedDevices.sh"
                        sh "sleep 20s"
                    }
                )
            }

            stage('Test') {
                // Reading content of the file
                def portsFileContent = readFile 'file.txt'

                // Split the file by next line
                def ports = portsFileContent.split('\n')

                // Getting device IDs to get properties of device
                def deviceIDFileContent = readFile 'IDs.txt'
                def deviceIDs = deviceIDFileContent.split('\n')

                // Define port and id as an pair
                def pairs = (0..<Math.min(ports.size(), deviceIDs.size())).collect { i -> [id: deviceIDs[i], port: ports[i]] }

                def steps = pairs.collectEntries { pair ->
                    ["UI Test on ${pair.id}", {
                        sh "#!/bin/bash -lx \n mono $testWorkspace/Tests/packages/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0/tools/nunit3-console.exe $testWorkspace/Tests/bin/Debug/MyProject.Core.dll --params=port=${pair.port}"
                    }]
                }
                parallel steps
            }
        }

catch (Exception e) {
    println(e);
}
finally {
    stage('Clean') {
        archiveArtifacts 'TestResult.xml'
        sh "#!/bin/bash -lx \n KillInstance.sh"   
    }
  }
}
```

This is a groovy script defining my pipeline. What I am trying to achieve with my plugin is, that the user who uses this plugin just inserts some pathvariables eg. path to his solution, or path to his github source. My Plugin then executes the above listed script automatically with the given parameters.

My problem is, that I cant find any documentation how to write such a pipeline construct in Java. If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate that.